# How do I get the value of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello How do I get the value of an object?
not: I do not want to use for,foreach,$.each I want to For only one value.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you have some HTML to share?

Comment: what about `object[key]`?

Comment: I did not understand your question? I have a list and want to get the value in

Answer (score 1):

Which value would you like?

Here is how to access the highlighted property:

```
var value = activeContract.DisembarkPlace;
```

Comment: Was very simple, for some reason I did not think :) thank you